# Linearity of a function on multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f \colon \mathbb {R}^n  \to  \mathbb {R} $ be a $C^1$ class function such that $f (\frac {x}{2}) = \frac {1}{2} f(x)$. Show that $f$ is linear.

**Hint**: show that $\nabla f (x) = \nabla f (0)$, for all x, and conclude that that $f (x) = \nabla f (x) \bullet x $ (dot product or scalar product).

I have no idea how can the hint help me. Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

If you can write $f$ as $f(x)=\nabla f(x)\cdot x=\nabla f(0)\cdot x$ it follows that $f$ is linear, since any linear transformation $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is in the form $g(x)=a\cdot x$ for some *fixed* vector $a\in\mathbb R^n$.